# Aspnet5 RC1 debug in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-debugging

1. Consider Windows 10, IIS 10, Aspnet5 RC1, a very basic Aspnet5 Web Application
2. app.Run -> returns a string to response
3. The web app is published to File System, approot, wwwroot folders are created
4. In IIS, virtual directory is made to point to wwwroot folder and the URL loads fine.

   Now, how to debug the IIS website (approot c# code)?
   In VS 2015, File -> Open Website  -> Local IIS -> Select the Aspnet5 website.
   It shows only wwwroot folder. C# code is present in approot folder

Comment: Why before debugging your web site code on IIS Server? Check successfully working  after Publish server

Comment: The website is working fine, just wanted to know similar to a normal Asp.Net web site, how to debug Aspnet5 websites deployed in IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET 5 apps after publishing are run by DNX process. If you have carefully observed when you deploy the ASP.NET 5 apps on IIS, the app pool has to be set as "No Managed Code".

Meaning that IIS now accepts request from browsers, passes to DNX with help of httpPlatformHandler, DNX does actual work of bootstrapping/ starting web apps.

This is different then traditional ASP.NET technologies.

So in Visual Studio 2015 Debug --> Attach to Process --> Select DNX program running, attach it and run. Check screen shot

It hits VS source code.

[image: Attach To Process of DNX]

Answer (score 0):

if the source code in you. Open Web site on Visual Studio and click -->Debug menu, choose --->Attach to Process. Look Available processes and find w3wp.exe, choose w3wp.exe after click Attach button, start your debug process.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your answer works in normal Asp.Net website. But for AspNet5 website , attaching to w3wp.exe does not hit breakpoint. As answered by Mithun - when attached to dnx.exe for that app pool, hits the breakpoint